# Erro ao utilizar o pacote Accord.Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Windows Forms C# e usando o .NetFramework 5.0 para gravar e salvar videos no computador com uma webcam. Faço uso do pacote Accord.Net para gravação.
Estava com o programa quase pronto, porem começou a dar um erro ao tentar instanciar e executar o form que estava fazendo a gravação.

**O ERRO:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo
> especificado.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();   //o erro acontece aqui
```

**VERIFICAÇÕES:**

Como esse erro aparece logo ao tentar instanciar o form1 que esta presente a gravação comecei a retirar do form1 parte a parte do que havia feito para ver o que estava causando o problema e verifiquei que o código passa da instancia do form1 e é executado normalmente se não instancio a classe `Accord.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice`.

```
private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
```

Só de instanciar essa classe já começa a dar o mesmo erro novamente. Tentei fazer a instalação e referencia de `CoreCompat.System.Drawing`, porém sem sucesso.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa e testes, para funcionar corretamente tive que utilizar o pacote AForge.Net para a captura da imagem da webcam, e passei a utilizar o pacote Accord.Net somente para compressão das imagens em vídeo e salvá-lo no meu computador. Ao mesclar as duas bibliotecas parou de aparecer esse erro na compilação.